# Every row of data frame as new slide in power point

Tags: r

I have df with n rows and I want to generate a powerpoint file with n slides where each slide will show column names and values in a specific row.
Can someone share code and libraries?

Comment: Sounds doable with the `officer` package and a loop.  https://davidgohel.github.io/officer/articles/powerpoint.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rmarkdown natively supports `output: powerpoint_presentation`, documented here: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/powerpoint-presentation.html

One example:

````
---
title: "mtcars"
author: r2evans
output: powerpoint_presentation
---

```{r setup, echo = FALSE, include = FALSE}
dat <- mtcars[1:3,]
```

```{r eachcar, echo = FALSE, results = 'asis'}
for (rn in seq_len(nrow(dat))) {
  cat("\n# ", rownames(dat)[rn], "\n\n")
  cat("MPG is ", dat$mpg[rn], "\n\n")
}
```
````

Output:

[image: powerpoint thumbnails]

For clarity, I threw in newlines rather liberally. Some experimentation will show you that at times one will not be enough, since some things in markdown require space between line-elements. I don't know all of them by memory, so I throw in the double-newline for safe-keeping. Since repeated newlines are reduced down (not preserved), it does not appear to have any adverse effect on the rendered product.

Comment: Can I also include images in this way? In one column of a data frame, I have values with a link for image and I want to display image

Comment: Images are just like they always are in rmarkdown: if plotted (base graphics, `ggplot2`, `plotly`, etc), then they are included after the code chunk; if an external image, you should be able to use the standard markdown method (e.g., `![alt text](path/to/image.png)` (and the path can be a full URL) ... typically outside of code chunks (though it is feasible to dynamically generate this markdown and have it used ... different story).